# How to remove varying shades of color in Opencv-Heatmap

Tags: python, opencv

I have an `img` of shape (1080 x 1920) with values ranging from [0...255], which is black and white. I am trying to convert the image to a "heatmap" representation. With 255 representing the most heat and `px` representing the least heat. I'd like to have all the `px` areas with high heat, say > 240, converted to the same color of red and similar for other heatmap colors (fixed color of red, blue, and green instead of  varying depth of color). Is there any way to do this?

My current code snippet to produce heatmap is

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask,(13,13),11)
heatmap_img = cv2.applyColorMap(blur, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
```

Here is the jpeg frame. There is a varying depth of red and green color based on `px` intensity. I wanted to produce a consistent color of red and green.

Heatmap:

[image: Heatmap]

Comment: Apply threshold and follow it up by color map

Comment: But, even setting threshold gives varying color depth. I want to get consistent color.

Comment: do your own color map, which has the desired properties (you want "banding" instead of a smooth table?) please __show__ what you mean. we can't read your mind and words are a poor substitute for pictures.

Comment: ah yes, the JET color map has various shades of each color. I'm afraid OpenCV only has a fixed set of colormaps. you'll have to use `cv.LUT`, or numpy/scipy methods, to do what you need. or... you discretize your data first, then apply the jet colormap. then you'll get a limited set of colors. -- note that colormaps are __not for segmentation__. they're for illustration, human consumption. you should never ever do any further processing on anything that is colormapped. your goal (_why_ you want what you want) is unclear so I'd better warn you...

Comment: I tried using custom colormap using matplotlib, still not being able to control the varies shades of color. Is there any way to have a minimum and maximum px density, and corresponding RGB color of it.